# c++ Algorithm to Compare various length vectors and isolate "unique", sort of

Tags: c++

I have a complex problem and have been trying to identify what needs to be a very, very efficient algorithm. I'm hoping i can get some ideas from you helpful folks. Here is the situation.

I have a vector of vectors. These nested vectors are of various length, all storing integers in a random order, such as (pseudocode):

```
vector_list = {
    { 1, 4, 2, 3 },
    { 5, 9, 2, 1, 3, 3 },
    { 2, 4, 2 },
    ...,
    100 more,
    { 8, 2, 2, 4 }
}
```

and so on, up to over 100 different vectors at a time inside vector_list. Note that the same integer can appear in each vector more than once. I need to remove from this vector_list any vectors that are duplicates of another vector. A vector is a duplicate of another vector if:

1. It has the same integers as the other vector (regardless of order). So if we have

   ```
     vec1 = { 1, 2, 3 }
     vec2 = { 2, 3, 1 }
   ```

These are duplicates and I need to remove one of them, it doesnt matter which one.

2. A vector contains all of the other integers of the other vector. So if we have

   ```
     vec1 = { 3, 2, 2 }
     vec2 = { 4, 2, 3, 2, 5 }
   ```

Vec2 has all of the ints of vec1 and is bigger, so i need to delete vec1 in favor of vec2

The problem is as I mentioned the list of vectors can be very big, over 100, and the algorithm may need to run as many as 1000 times on a button click, with a different group of 100+ vectors over 1000 times. Hence the need for efficiency. I have considered the following:

1. Sorting the vectors may make life easier, but as I said, this has to be efficient, and i'd rather not sort if i didnt have to.
2. It's more complicated by the fact that the vectors aren't in any order with respect to their size. For example, if the vectors in the list were ordered by size:

   ```
   vector_list = {
       {           },
       {           },
       {        },
       {        },
       {      },
       ...
       { },
       { }
   }
   ```

It might make life easier, but that seems like it would take a lot of effort and I'm not sure about the gain.

The best effort I've had so far to try and solve this problem is:

```
// list of vectors, just 4 for illustration, but in reality more like 100, with lengths from 5 to 15 integers long
std::vector<std::vector<int>> vector_list;
vector_list.push_back({9});
vector_list.push_back({3, 4, 2, 8, 1});
vector_list.push_back({4, 2});
vector_list.push_back({1, 3, 2, 4});

std::vector<int>::iterator it;
int i;
int j;
int k;

// to test if a smaller vector is a duplicate of a larger vector, i copy the smaller vector, then
// loop through ints in the larger vector, seeing if i can find them in the copy of the smaller. if i can,
// i remove the item from the smaller copy, and if the size of the smaller copy reaches 0, then the smaller vector
// was a duplicate of the larger vector and can be removed.
std::vector<int> copy;

// flag for breaking a for loop below
bool erased_i;

// loop through vector list
for ( i = 0; i < vector_list.size(); i++ ) 
{
    // loop again, so we can compare every vector to every other vector
    for ( j = 0; j < vector_list.size(); j++ ) 
    {
        // don't want to compare a vector to itself
        if ( i != j ) 
        {
            // if the vector in i loop is at least as big as the vector in j loop
            if ( vector_list[i].size() >= vector_list[j].size() ) 
            {
                // copy the smaller j vector
                copy = vector_list[j];
                
                // loop through each item in the larger i vector
                for ( k = 0; k < vector_list[i].size(); k++ ) {
                
                    // if the item in the larger i vector is in the smaller vector, 
                    // remove it from the smaller vector
                    it = std::find(copy.begin(), copy.end(), vector_list[i][k]);
                    
                    if (it != copy.end()) 
                    {
                        // erase
                        copy.erase(it);
                        
                        
                        // if the smaller vector has reached size 0, then it must have been a smaller duplicate that
                        // we can delete
                        if ( copy.size() == 0 ) {
                            vector_list.erase(vector_list.begin() + j);
                            j--;
                        }
                    }
                 
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // otherwise vector j must be bigger than vector i, so we do the same thing
                // in reverse, trying to erase vector i
                copy = vector_list[i];
            
                erased_i = false;
                for ( k = 0; k < vector_list[j].size(); k++ ) {
                    it = std::find(copy.begin(), copy.end(), vector_list[j][k]);
                    if (it != copy.end()) {
                        copy.erase(it);
                        if ( copy.size() == 0 ) {
                            vector_list.erase(vector_list.begin() + i);
                            
                            // put an extra flag so we break out of the j loop as well as the k loop
                            erased_i = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                }
                if ( erased_i ) {
                    // break the j loop because we have to start over with whatever
                    // vector is now in position i
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

std::cout << "ENDING VECTORS\n";
// TERMINAL OUTPUT:

vector_list[0]
[9]
vector_list[1]
[3, 4, 2, 8, 1]
```

So this function gives me the right results, as these are the 2 unique vectors. It also gives me the correct results if i push the initial 4 vectors in reverse order, so the smallest one comes last for example. But it feels so inefficient comparing every vector to every other vector. Plus i have to create these "copies" and try to reduce them to 0 .size() with every comparison I make. very inefficient.

Anyways, any ideas on how I could make this speedier would be much appreciated. Maybe some kind of organization by vector length, I dunno.... It seems wasteful to compare them all to each other.

Thanks!

Comment: Does it matter if the numbers in the inner vectors get reordered?

Comment: Good question. It would not be ideal, because the order they get filled is significant in that i can tell whats going on. but its not required, so short answer no it would not matter

Comment: Recently, I wrote an article on my blog [here](https://m-peko.github.io/craft-cpp/posts/zipping-by-the-longest-range/). It's about zipping by the longest range. You can do the same here... Zip all the vectors together and extract the unique values. With this, you will get only one for loop

Comment: Hi Nutcracker thanks for your comment. That is certainly and interesting solution. I do have a question though, I've actually only been coding in c++ for less than 2 weeks so i'm a bit of a newb here. I skipped most of the technical parts of your blog and just looked at the output you can get from zipping. It looks like you're basically transposing the vectors. I'm not sure how i would figure the unique values from that. For example, with the 4 vectors in my solution, the first transposed vector would be { 9, 3, 4, 1 }, the second would be { 0, 4, 2, 3 }. How would I use this information ?

Comment: Why did you say sorting will take time?  Your current solution seems to be `O(n^2)`, while `std::sort` takes `O(n log n)`.  If you find yourself writing nested loops, that is almost always going to be the slowest method.

Comment: Also, you never mentioned if you have memory constraints.  You could sort those vectors and throw them into a `std::set<std::vector<int>>`, which would automatically eliminate the duplicates.  Once the duplicates are gone, then now the problem gets reduced down to figuring out whether a vector is a "subset" of another vector.  But I really would start with the first step -- sort and place in a set -- time that and see if it is satisfactory.  If it is, you've reduced the problem down to the last step.

Comment: *The problem is as I mentioned the list of vectors can be very big, over 100, and the algorithm may need to run as many as 1000 times on a button click,* -- The user clicks the button, and let's say they wait 2 or 3 seconds -- is that really a big issue?  If this were a low-latency trading system, then yes -- but if we're talking about a human waiting a couple of seconds for a response -- well?

Comment: Hey Paul thanks for the response. I said sorting would take time because i didnt see how i could do it and avoid the nested loop. i like your idea with the map though I'll see what i can come up with there

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Users are impatient by definition (according to my experience). On the other hand, it sometimes helps to explain them that saving a second for user experience can consume weeks or months of development... ;-)

Comment: It's a lot more complicated than that paul. The sole purpose of this program is not to sort these integers, this is a tiny part of a big machine that is definitely a significant bottleneck, but just a bottleneck

Comment: @GeoffL -- ok, I understand your concern.  So you need to consider what is an acceptable wait time.  Data still has to be processed, regardless.

Comment: @scheff ok thanks I didnt know that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach is to copy the vectors that pass the test to an empty vector.
May be inefficient.
May have bugs.
HTH :)

[C++ Fiddle](http://cpp.sh/8tl5he)

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

int main(int, char **) {
  using namespace std;
  using vector_of_integers = vector<int>;
  using vector_of_vectors  = vector<vector_of_integers>;
  vector_of_vectors in     = {
    { 1, 4, 2, 3 },         // unique
    { 5, 9, 2, 1, 3, 3 },   // unique
    { 3, 2, 1 },            // exists
    { 2, 4, 2 },            // exists
    { 8, 2, 2, 4 },         // unique
    { 1, 1, 1 },            // exists
    { 1, 2, 2 },            // exists
    { 5, 8, 2 },            // unique
  };

  vector_of_vectors out;

  // doesnt_contain_vector returns true when there is no entry in out that is superset of any of the passed vectors
  auto doesnt_contain_vector = [&out](const vector_of_integers &in_vector) {
    // is_subset returns true a vector contains all the integers of the passed vector
    auto is_subset = [&in_vector](const vector_of_integers &out_vector) {
      // contained returns true when the vector contains the passed integer
      auto contained = [&out_vector](int i) {
        return find(out_vector.cbegin(), out_vector.cend(), i) != out_vector.cend();
      };
      return all_of(in_vector.cbegin(), in_vector.cend(), contained);
    };
    return find_if(out.cbegin(), out.cend(), is_subset) == out.cend();
  };

  copy_if(in.cbegin(), in.cend(), back_insert_iterator<vector_of_vectors>(out), doesnt_contain_vector);

  // show results
  for (auto &vi: out) {
    copy(vi.cbegin(), vi.cend(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ", "));
    cout << "\n";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop through the vectors and for each vector, map the count of unique values occurring in it. `unordered_map<int, int>` would suffice for this, let's call it `M`.

Also maintain a `set<unordered_map<int, int>>`, say `S`, ordered by the size of `unordered_map<int, int>` in decreasing order.

Now we will have to compare contents of `M` with the contents of `unordered_map`s in `S`. Let's call `M'`, the current `unordered_map` in `S` being compared with `M`. `M` will be a subset of `M'` only when the count of all the elements in `M` is less than or equal to the count of their respective elements in `M'`. If that's the case then it's a duplicate and we'll not insert. For any other case, we'll insert. Also notice that if the size of `M` is greater than the size of `M'`, `M` can't be a subset of `M'`. That means we can insert `M` in `S`. This can be used as a pre-condition to speed things up. Maintain the indices of vectors which weren't inserted in `S`, these are the duplicates and have to be deleted from `vector_list` in the end.

Time Complexity: `O(N*M) + O(N^2*D) + O(N*log(N)) = O(N^2*D)` where `N` is the number of vectors in `vector_list`, `M` is the average size of the vectors in `vector_list` and `D` is the average size of `unordered_map`'s in `S`. This is for the worst case when there aren't any duplicates. For average case, when there are duplicates, the second complexity will come down.

Edit: The above procedure will create a problem. To fix that, we'll need to make `unordered_map`s of all vectors, store them in a vector `V`, and sort that vector in decreasing order of the size of `unordered_map`. Then, we'll start from the biggest in this vector and apply the above procedure on it. This is necessary because, a subset, say `M1` of a set `M2`, can be inserted into `S` before `M2` if the respective vector of `M1` comes before the respective vector of `M2` in `vector_list`. So now we don't really need `S`, we can compare them within `V` itself. Complexity won't change.

Edit 2: The same problem will occur again if sizes of two `unordered_map`s are the same in `V` when sorting `V`. To fix that, we'll need to keep the contents of `unordered_map`s in some order too. So just replace `unordered_map` with `map` and in the comparator function, if the size of two `map`s is the same, compare element by element and whenever the keys are not the same for the very first time or are same but the `M[key]` is not the same, put the bigger element before the other in `V`.

Edit 3: New Time Complexity: `O(N*M*log(D)) + O(N*D*log(N)) + O(N^2*D*log(D)) = O(N^2*D*log(D))`. Also you might want to pair the `map`s with the index of the respective vectors in `vector_list` so as to know which vector you must delete from `vector_list` when you find a duplicate in `V`.

IMPORTANT: In sorted `V`, we must start checking from the end just to be safe (in case we choose to delete a duplicate from `vector_list` as well as `V` whenever we encounter it). So for the last `map` in `V` compare it with the rest of the `map`s before it to check if it is a duplicate.

Example:

> ```
> vector_list = {
>   {1, 2, 3},
>   {2, 3, 1},
>   {3, 2, 2},
>   {4, 2, 3, 2, 5},
>   {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 2},
>   {2, 3, 4, 5, 6},
>   {1, 5}
> }
> ```

Creating `map`s of respective vectors:

> ```
> V = {
>   {1->1, 2->1, 3->1},
>   {1->1, 2->1, 3->1},
>   {2->2, 3->1},
>   {2->2, 3->1, 4->1, 5->1},
>   {1->1, 2->2, 3->1, 4->1, 6->1},
>   {2->1, 3->1, 4->1, 5->1, 6->1},
>   {1->1, 5->1}
> }
> ```

After sorting:

> ```
> V = {
>   {1->1, 2->2, 3->1, 4->1, 6->1},
>   {2->1, 3->1, 4->1, 5->1, 6->1},
>   {2->2, 3->1, 4->1, 5->1},
>   {1->1, 2->1, 3->1},
>   {1->1, 2->1, 3->1},
>   {1->1, 5->1},
>   {2->2, 3->1}
> }
> ```

After deleting duplicates:

> ```
> V = {
>   {1->1, 2->2, 3->1, 4->1, 6->1},
>   {2->1, 3->1, 4->1, 5->1, 6->1},
>   {2->2, 3->1, 4->1, 5->1},
>   {1->1, 5->1}
> }
> ```

Edit 4: I tried coding it up. Running it a 1000 times on a list of 100 vectors, the size of each vector being in range [1-250], the range of the elements of vector being [0-50] and assuming the input is available for all the 1000 times, it takes around 2 minutes on my machine. It goes without saying that there is room for improvement in my code (and my machine).

Comment: thanks for your response! that is a very sophisticated solution I will try to implement it tomorrow and give it a try. I've been readoing up on std::includes which can check if a vector is a subset of another vector. they have to be sorted, but thats ok. Do you think that might be helpful as well

Comment: I would expect `std::set<std::unordered_map<int, int>>` to not compile.

Comment: @paler123 I said it should be ordered by size of `unordered_map`. Kindly read the complete answer as I finally go on to state that we don't really need a `set`.

Comment: @GeoffL yes, for `vector` it is possible. But unfortunately we are using `map`. And not only we need to check for existence of keys of a `map` in another `map` but if a key exists in both the maps, then we also check for their values. I don't know if there is such an algorithm in STL to do that for `map`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this. I use `std::sort` and `std::includes`. Perhaps this is not the most effective solution.

```
// sort all nested vectors
std::for_each(vlist.begin(), vlist.end(), [](auto& v)
{
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
});

// sort vector of vectors by length of items
std::sort(vlist.begin(), vlist.end(), [](const vector<int>& a, const vector<int>& b)
{
    return a.size() < b.size();
});

// exclude all duplicates
auto i = std::begin(vlist);
while (i != std::end(vlist)) {
    if (any_of(i+1, std::end(vlist), [&](const vector<int>& a){
        return std::includes(std::begin(a), std::end(a), std::begin(*i), std::end(*i));
    }))
        i = vlist.erase(i);
    else
        ++i;
}
```